# Update properties value with event in template ANGULAR

Tags: angular, typescript

(Working with Angular)
Hello, i have a list of checkbox inputs like this:

`<input (click)="onCheck(check1)" type="checkbox" />`

The onCheck method is:

`onCheck(check:boolean){ check = !check }`
and a list of boolean properties like this:

`public check1:boolean = false`

what I want to achieve is that when cliking in the checkbox input, the value of the property in the argument changes.

I tried:

```
  onCheck(check:any){
     check = !check

     this.check1 = check
  }
```

But i want the method to be dynamic for my checkbox list,

and in the template i tried

`<input (click)="onCheck(this.check1)" type="checkbox" />`

With the same results. Can you what i am doing wrong, why the value of the boolean property doesnt change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't change the `check` parameter in your onCheck function.
   The simplest way is to bind the `check` property to your `check1` attribute.
2. Also don't use `click` event as it doesn't provide the check value, use `change` instead:

Modify the template:

```
<input (change)="onCheck($event)" [checked]="check1" type="checkbox" />
```

Modify the callback:

```
onCheck(check:Event){
  const isChecked = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).checked;
  this.check1 = isChecked;
}
```